# Is password-less authentication Windows possiable

Tags: linux, windows, password-protection, winrm

Is Password-less linux to windows `pywinrm` connection possible.

Something similar to `ssh-copy-id` in linux to linux

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't done this myself, as far as I can tell, this should be possible. If the Windows machine you are attempting to access is on a domain.

I HAVE set up smartcard/certificate authentication on domains before. If you add your public key to your account in AD, you can authenticate to your domain account using a smartcard or pki cert.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754866(v=ws.11).aspx

I have also used kinit (which is what pywinrm uses for kerberos/domain authentication) to authenticate to Windows servers using domain credentials. Although I did not use a certificate/smartcard to authenticate, from what I have read, I believe kinit (pkinit) will support smart cards and possibly plain old certificate files.

https://k5wiki.kerberos.org/wiki/Pkinit_configuration#Client_identity_on_the_command_line

http://honk.sigxcpu.org/con/PKINIT__Kerberos_v5_with_Smart_Cards.html

Before you can authenticate with kinit, you would need to set up your domains and realms. This blog post is about setting up Ansible to administer Windows machines but, since Ansible uses PyWinrm to authenticate, there is a pretty good walkthrough for setting up kinit for domain authentication (and therefore he talks about how to set up your realms, etc.).

https://aseemkblog.wordpress.com/2016/06/01/configuring-ansible-to-manage-windows-system-over-powershell/

If you ever get this working, let me know. Would definitely be interested to see if someone gets this working. Just getting kinit auth working with Windows domain authentication is a bit of a maze but, once that part is done, you're about 75% of the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible!

There is a Windows version of ssh-copy-id I found on GitHub:
https://github.com/zhengyi-yang/ssh-copy-id/tree/master/dist

Make sure you have your public key generated already.